# I'm looking for advice on a WP error. After WP update the plugin page & WP-admi won't load. Too few arguments to function wpdb::prepare()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin that appears to be not working.  The page that references it is completely blank and so is the WP-Admin page.  Inspecting the html on the referenced plugin page revealed this:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wpdb::prepare(), 1 passed in /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/career-portfolio-premium/classes/CRPHelper.php on line 35 and exactly 2 expected in /home/******/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1295.
```

Here is line 35 from CRPHelper:

```
  $query = @$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".CRP_TABLE_PORTFOLIOS." WHERE id='{$pid}'");
    $res = $wpdb->get_results( $query , OBJECT );
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit: [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) is expecting 2 parameters but your CRPHelper class is passing just one.

This should fix it:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".CRP_TABLE_PORTFOLIOS." WHERE id=%s", array($pid));
```

Comment: Thanks Cabrerahector! That fixed that problem and now there are 7 other errors.  I believe this plugin has been abandon.  I was hoping to get it working so that I could transfer the info to another plugin but it appears to be too much of a hassle.

Comment: Thanks for you help on this though!